# Processing statement error in loop

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   // new fetchEmailID().fetchIDs();
    new UserInputAndDefaulValues().validateUserInputAndDefaultValues();
    while(!UserInputAndDefaulValues.start_mailing_flag)
    {
        //System.out.println(UserInputAndDefaulValues.start_mailing_flag);

    }
    MainExecutor.main_executor();
}
```

When I uncomment

```
//System.out.println(UserInputAndDefaulValues.start_mailing_flag);
```

the condition in while loop works correctly and the while loop ends on false condition. But as I comment it, the loop goes in infinite loop even when it should escape. Why is that behavior and that too just with one output statement?

Comment: share your UserInputAndDefaulValues class

Comment: total guessing: Isn't the compiler "clever" enough to remove the complete while loop when it is empty because even the while condition does nothing...

Comment: @dhamibirendra a jFrame is called from UserInputAndDefaulValues class, and on some button click event in jFrame, this static start_mailing_flag is turned true.

Comment: @warrenFaith i tried puting the if(UserInputAndDefaulValues.start_mailing_flag)break; inside while loop but that did no favour

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See: [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you change the `start_mailing_flag` in another thread (otherwise, no wonder the loop goes on forever).

The compiler optimizes such cases and removes the condition check after the first time. It changes the code to something like this:

```
if (!UserInputAndDefaulValues.start_mailing_flag) {
    while(true)
    {
        //System.out.println(UserInputAndDefaulValues.start_mailing_flag);
    }
}
```

You need to define  `start_mailing_flag` as `volatile`:

```
public class UserInputAndDefaulValues {
   public static volatile boolean start_mailing_flag;
   .....
}
```

Comment: @user2368055 - It'd be nice if you could accept the answer :)

Comment: i said it worked, and i even upvoted, any other way to accept the answer?

Comment: @user2368055 - Yes, if you choose the V sign (under the answer's score) you accept the answer which states that you as the question owner accepted this answer as the correct one. You'll get 2 points for doing it.

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, your code is not *correctly synchronized*. In other words, it contains a *data race* on the `start_mailing_flag`.

Now, the method `PrintStream#println` is `synchronized` so calling it forces the JIT compiler to avoid certain optimizations (namely, *hoisting*) on the code in question. As soon as you remove that statement, the effect is gone.

To conclude, when you uncomment the `println`, your code works *by pure chance* and as a side-effect of calling a `synchronized` method. It remains as thread-unsafe as before.